# DB2 for Windows: where to find the configuration file similar to tnsname.ora of Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, db2, db2-luw

I am new in DB2. I write a little C# application and need to find the (client) configuration file, similar to tnsnames.ora in Oracle, because I want to get some information from it (e.g. hostname, port, service name). I use 64-bit Windows 7 and 8.
Can someone tell me where and how to find it?
Any help and hints are highly appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: there isn't such a file. The longer answer is: the data similar to what can be found in `tnsnames.ora` are contained in the system node (`sqlnodir`) and database (`sqldbdir`) catalog files, which are binary files and aren't human-readable. I'm not sure about their exact location on Windows, but I'd expect to find them somewhere under the DB2 client instance (`C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\<DB2 copy name>`).

In addition to that, the client can be configured by means of a `db2dsdriver.cfg` file, which *is* a human-readable XML file (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0054799.html?lang=en). It does not exist by default -- you need to create it manually.

Comment: I have searched in C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\<DB2 copy name> but there is no file contains information I need. Please tell me where to find **sqlnodir** and **sqldbdir**.

Comment: These files are in a binary format.  You would use the db2 commands `list node directory` and `list database directory` to see the contents; to add entries use `catalog tcpip node` and `catalog database`.   See documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In db2 there are db2cfexp, db2cfimp utilities for exporting/importing connection information to/from a text file, similar to tnsname.ora in Oracle.

Comment: well thank you. but this question is quite old (from 2014). I do not work with it anymore.